# can we publish app that is unpublished in google developer console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

1. Can we publish application that is unpublished in Google developer console?
2. If we republish this application then all installs, reviews and rating are preserved or not?

Answer (score 2):

For both answer is `YES`. Now you can republish any unpublished app anytime. All the reviews and rating will always be preserved either that app is in publish state or unpublished state.